# calculate average percentage of measurements over time

Tags: statistics, average, time-series, discrete-time

Let us say I have weekly measurements over time and I have a target measure for each week. Is it too naive to calcuate the relative difference:

```
(measurement - target)/ target
```

per week and then take the arithmetic mean, especially when the magnitudes of measurements and targets vary over time? Maybe one should z-score first and then take the average (arithmetic mean)?

The overall intention is to gauge the average difference between target and measurement over time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, but clearly, you have to compute the statistic you're interested in estimating.  The statistic you've computed if the relative difference between the measurement and the target.  If you want to estimate the absolute difference between the measurement and the target, then I don't see how this can be of any use, but it's not clear to me which you want.

Comment: I want to estimate the average percentage difference over time. Sorry if this is not clear?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.  What is the formula for "average percentage difference over time"?

Comment: Take the arithmetic mean of all percentage differences!?

Comment: What do you mean by percentage difference?  Please give an example with numbers.

Comment: The formula is clearly stated in the question. Sorry maybe I am missing something?

Comment: That's the relative difference, as I stated in my first comment.  When you compute percentages, $100$ appears somewhere in the formula, remember?  The average value of those relative differences is an estimate for the expected value of the relative difference.  If you want a confidence interval, proceed as usual.  The numbers you have computed are the ones you want.

Comment: Sorry I changed the term.